# Como usar expressão regular no input?

Tags: javascript, validação

Gostaria de colocar no onkeyup do input uma expressão usando html ou js um exemplo

```
onkeyup='this.value=this.value.replace(/[^0-9]*/g,"")'
```

esse só aceita números quero adaptar isso

```
/^(ht|f)tps?:\/\/[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z0-9-!-@-#-$-%-¨-&-*-?\.]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/
```

para validar url

Comment: Seu primeiro exemplo elimina tudo o que não é número da entrada, enquanto o usuário digita. Não é exatamente uma boa prática, mas é factível. Entretanto, não vejo como isso poderia ser aplicado a uma URL - pois pra digitar uma URL válida (ex.: `http://google.com`) você vai necessariamente passar por uma inválida (ex.: `h`, `ht`, `htt`, `http`, `http:` etc). Sugiro não validar no `onkeyup`, mas em algum outro lugar; de preferência depois que o usuário já terminou de digitar (ex.: `onblur` do campo ou `onsubmit` do formulário)

Comment: O código de validação nesse caso realmente não é trivial. Eu sugiro dar uma olhada em plugins como o [jQuery Validaiton](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Veja o [exemplo para URLs](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/), ele faz uma primeira validação ao perder o foco e daí em diante valida a cada edição.

Comment: Muito bom é mais complexo e atende o que preciso

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Ótima sugestão, nesse caso embora a "validação" seja feita a cada edição, ela não **altera** a entrada do usuário: somente diz se ela é ou não válida. E isso sim é um bom comportamento, do ponto de vista da usabilidade (há um tempo fiz [uma pergunta no SOen semelhante a essa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9205164/520779), e também [fui desaconselhado a alterar o input enquanto o usuário digitava](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9205475/520779)).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Claro, por que não? Fique à vontade para usar o conteúdo do meu primeiro comentário e/ou da resposta linkada no segundo, se isso ajudar a torná-la uma resposta de fato.

Answer (score 2):

Conforme [comentário do mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/32972/como-usar-express%c3%a3o-regular-no-input#comment62835_32972), "máscaras" para URL não são uma boa ideia. Uma estratégia melhor é validar a URL após a perda de foco com algum tipo de indicação visual.

Como esse tipo de estratégia de validação não é trivial sugiro a utilização de uma das muitas bibliotecas para validação. Em especial posso recomendar a biblioteca [jQuery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) que possui [um método](http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/) pronto para tratar urls. A Estratégia dessa biblioteca é fazer uma primeira validação "preguiçosa" quando o campo perde o foco; caso exista algum erro o campo passa a ser validado ativamente durante a edição.

#### HTML

```
<form id="formulario">
   <label for="minhaurl">Minha URL: </label>
   <input id="minhaurl" name="minhaurl">
   <!--...-->
</form>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$("#formulario").validate({
  rules: {
    minhaurl: {
      required: true,
      url: true
    }
  }
});
```